# Make navigation bar item float right

Tags: html, css

I've been following this tutorial:

http://www.mrc-productivity.com/techblog/?p=1049

I want to make a single item in the navigation bar float to the right, but simply adding float:right; to that particular item didn't do anything. In fact, changing the float:left to float:right only reversed the ordering of the navigation bar items.

Here's a snippet:

```css
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 margin: 0;
 z-index: 99;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #366b82;
}

.navbar {
 height: 50px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
 border-right: 1px solid #54879d;
}

.navbar li {
 height: auto;
 width: 150px;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 list-style: none;
 font: normal bold 12px/1.2em Arial, Verdana, Helvetica;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #366b82;
}

#navright {
 float: right;
}

.navbar a {
 padding: 18px 0;
 border-left: 1px solid #54879d;
 border-right: 1px solid #1f5065;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 display: block;
}

.navbar li:hover, a:hover {
 background-color: #54879d;
}

.navbar li ul {
 display: none;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.navbar li:hover ul {
 display: block;
}

.navbar li ul li {
 background-color: #54879d;
}

.navbar li ul li a {
 border-left: 1px solid #1f5065; 
 border-right: 1px solid #1f5065; 
 border-top: 1px solid #74a3b7;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #1f5065;
}

.navbar li ul li a:hover {
 background-color: #366b82;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="wrap">
  <ul class="navbar">
   <li><a href="/dashboard">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Registers</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">People</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Operational</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Financial</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
   <li id="navright"><a id="logout" href="/login">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</body>
```

```
<li id="navright"><a id="logout" href="/login">Logout</a></li>
```

Just need to get that "Logout" button to be on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the containing UL element have a width of 100%

```
.navbar {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid #54879d;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/txve55jn/2/